# Mobile Web App | Over Zoomed on Rotation + Hiding URL Bar

Tags: javascript, web-applications, meta-tags

Here are my METAs

```
<META name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;" />
<META name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```

and this is my JavaSCript supposedly hiding the URL bar (which is quirky)

```
window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0, 1);}, 100);
  insert();
}
```

1. The text when turned to horizontal position is extremely large, and is perfect in the vertical version. Any ideas as to why?
2. On some pages the URL bar is hidden entirely, on others it's only partially hidden. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For disabling scaling try to use this meta tag:

```
<META name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;"/>
```